# Can I ignore the last k while expanding (a + b) % k?

Tags: algorithm, math, modular-arithmetic

Today I was trying to solve a problem that involved modular arithmetic. I was not able to solve it. So I looked it up on Geeks for Geeks

[image]

The above image shows what the author did. I know modular addition for two numbers

**(a + b) % m   =  (a % m + b % m) % m**

This works for any positive values of **a** and **b**

When I consider the equation the author used in the image.

**a % k + b % k = 0**

I substituted some random values for **a** , **b** and **k** to see if it really works. It turns out it fails for the input values **a = 2, b = 5** and **k = 7**.

**2 % 7 + 5 % 7 = 7 ≠ 0**

When I considered the last equation. It worked.

**b % k = (k - a % k) % k**

**(5 % 7) = (7 - 2 % 7) % 7**

**5 % 7 = 5 % 7**

**(a + b) % k = c**

When I solved the above equation with the same idea as the author, I got

(**a + b) % k = c**

**a % k + b % k = c**

**b % k = (c - a % k + k) % k**

It works for any positive values of **a, b, c** and **k**

In the equation,

**(a + b) % k  = (a % k + b % k) % k**

Can I just ignore the last **k** and proceed while expanding **(a + b) % k** ?. I wonder how the absence of the last **k** doesn't affect the final result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `a = b = 0` is a counterexample.

Indeed, the final formula is incorrect, assuming that `%` denotes the remainder of truncating division. Let `a = 1` and `b = -1`. (In Python, or for nonnegative integers, it's OK.)

This is why mathematicians prefer to deal in equivalence mod `K`, which avoids the issue of where to put the mod operator.